# How can I change the appearance of the input box when using selectize in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, selectize.js

I would appreciate it very much if someone could help me with this question. I have not been able to figure it out on my own.

I am using the following jQuery to create an input box:

```
<script>
        
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            
            $('#customer_codes_served').selectize({
                delimiter: ',',
                persist: false,
                create: function(input) {
                    return {
                        value: input,
                        text: input
                    }
                },
                onBlur : function(input){                    
                    agent_app_change_hander(document.getElementById("customer_codes_served"), "customer_codes_served", "customer_codes_served", "text");
                },
                });
                });

</script>
```

This is the html:

```
    <input class="form-control" id="customer_codes_served" name="customer_codes_served" onblur="javascript:agent_app_change_hander(this,'customer_codes_served','customer_codes_served','text');" placeholder="Customer Codes Served" size="300" style="display: none" type="text" value="" /></div>
```

This works to create the input box, but how can I customize certain aspects of its appearance, such as height and border width? I tried to another class for css, but then the function won't work. Is that the correct approach? Perhaps I just don't understand correctly how to add a class to JQuery.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a specific reason to create an input from jquery? you could also create one beforehand and hide its visibility. There are some online inputbox generators that you can google search. Otherwise you should be able to target it using class or id in CSS.

Comment: JQuery is the approach by a third party that coded it. I do not want to use a different approach.  Even though I do know html and CSS, since this is in JavaScript/JQuery, what I don't understand is how I can change the appearance of the input box using a class or id in CSS. Thank you.

Comment: You can definitely look out some input generators online for the css code. Then you can add an id or class to target your input.

Comment: What I don't understand is, how do I add an id or class to the JavaScript?  Where do I put it? On what line? Do I put a comma or plus sign before the id or class? If you could show me in the JavaScript above, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_create put x.id="" and x.className="" and you're good to go

Comment: Maybe you can use the `.css()` jquery method after `.selectsize()`. See https://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Servesh - Thank you, but I don't understand how and where to put your solution in my code.  Would you be kind enough to insert your solution in my code above for me? I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it, if someone could help me with this outstanding problem I have.  Thank You.